# Restricting distinct keyword on single column in Sql plus

Tags: sql, distinct, sqlplus, unique-key

```
INSERT INTO DEPT(Dept_ID, Dept_Name)
(SELECT DISTINCT department_id, last_name
FROM my_employee);
```

**department_id in my_employee table may contain Duplicate key
but Dept_ID is PRIMARY KEY.**

**error displayed (ORA-00001: unique constraint (ROHITRAJ.SYS_C0013013) violated) .**

Above code has been changed as shown below, but it still doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO DEPT(Dept_ID, Dept_Name)
(SELECT (DISTINCT department_id), last_name
FROM my_employee);
```

Is it possible to insert data into a column that contains unique key from a column containing duplicates?

Comment: Are you trying to populate Dept Names with Last Name of an employee?

Comment: limit distinct keyword to one column[Check This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732765/limit-distinct-keyword-to-one-column)

Comment: If there are multiple rows with the same `department_id` but (possibly) different `last_name` values, *which* `last_name` value should be selected? You need to articulate a *rule* by which those values should be selected - first, to us, and second, to your database system.

Comment: @knkarthick24 I was just experimenting, really dumb naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to insert data into a column that contains unique key from a column containing duplicates?

Your **Primary Key** field must contain unique values only. It will throw an exception if you are trying to insert duplicate data on it.

If you want create another column that will handle the `department_id` and just store an autonumber on the `Dept_ID`.

**Try this:**

```
INSERT INTO DEPT(Dept_ID, Department_id, Dept_Name)
(SELECT rownum, department_id, last_name
FROM my_employee);
```

**Note:** (rownum only works for Oracle it means row number.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can't i do it without using two column name created for one purpose? Any way to insert data without using another column because i want to make Department_id a foreign key of Dept_ID.